# can Homebrew be used on a Centos computer

Tags: centos, php, mysql, homebrew

I just installed Centos 6.4 minimal on an old computer with an internet connection threw my iMac. Set it up as a development server. Installments required: `Nginx, Apache, PHP-5, Mysql, Redis, Mongodb etc`.

Is yum just as good as Homebrew on my iMac or can I install Homebrew on the Centos computer?

What is the best way to go about it. Or how are you doing it?

thanks

This is what I need to install sofar

```
yum install man to install the manuals
yum install bind-utils to install basic network tools (host, nslookup..)
yum install wget to install wget, that will help you grab files from the internet
yum install setuptool to install the user-friendly text mode menu utility
yum install system-config-firewall to install the firewall plugin for the tool above
yum install system-config-network-tui to install the network plugin for the tool above
yum install openssh-server to install the SSH server, which will allow you to connect to your system
yum install openssh-clients to install the SSH client, which will allow you to connect to other systems
yum install NetworkManager to install the service that manage the network connections
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are forks of Homebrew targeted for linux, such as [Linuxbrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew).  However, Homebrew is trying to emulate something like `yum` or other package managers (`aptitude`, `pacman`, etc.) - so as far as "is it just as good", not in my experience as the "recipes" are fairly limited - but it does provide some nice functionality on Mac (since there is no CLI package manager).

All that said - I wouldn't opt for it over a built in/default package manager for Linux.